# Log4j Internationalization

Tags: log4j

Log4j documentation says that it supports internationalization, but no where it provides any details of how to achieve that. Has anyone work on this or can suggest something regarding this please?

Comment: logging is for development quality and debugging not for customers.Why would you need to use multiple languages for logging?

Comment: Like dates and currency, and also language if possible it can be localized. Log4j documentation does say that it supports internationalization, what does not supposed to mean? it doesnot say how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never used it but the feature seems to be provided by the [Category.l7dlog](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/Category.html#l7dlog%28org.apache.log4j.Priority,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%5B%5D,%20java.lang.Throwable%29) methods (added in [Release 0.8.4 - 2000-05-01](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/changes-report.html#Release_0.8.4_-_2000-05-01)).

As I never used it you have to search for more information on your own or switch to an up to date logging framework like e.g. [slf4j](http://www.slf4j.org/localization.html) with better documentation.

Comment: Why downvote? Isn't this an information regarding the problem addressed in the question ("_or can suggest something regarding this please_")?

Answer (score 1):

Are you familiar with [SLF4J](http://www.slf4j.org)? It can work in conjunction with log4j. SLF4J supports [localisation](http://slf4j.org/localization.html) built on top the [cal10n](http://cal10n.qos.ch/) project.